# Passing Values So I Have One Method

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a scenario where I have 5 possible customers id's to work with. Right now I am using 5 methods but aside from the customerid value, all the code is the same. I want to clean my code up a bit so I am not using 5 methods but one method with a conditional statement. I am guessing there is a way for me to write this in specflow? I am not sure how it needs to be written out.

as an example.

```
Feature:
Given I am using customerid(111) 

Step:
[Given]
public void Given_I_am_using_customer(int)
if (number = 111)
{
do this
}
else if  (number = 222)
{
do this
}
else if  (number = 333)
{
do this
}
}
```

Comment: Are you just starting to use SpecFlow? If so you might want to check out BDDfy, it has been amazing for us and does what you are trying easily (basically as written there)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it was me I would do this:

```
[Given]
public void Given_I_am_using_customer(Customer customer)
{
     ///do some stuff with the customer
}

[StepArgumentTransformation]
public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
{
    switch (id)
        case 111
            return new Customer();// create a '111' customer here
        case 222
            return new Customer();// create a '222' customer here
        case 333
            return new Customer();// create a '333' customer here
        case 444
            return new Customer();// create a '444' customer here
        etc
}
```

Comment: I ran a variation of what you mentioned here and got it working. Thanks Sam!